# Can markdown grammar be parsed using a CFG?

Tags: parsing, markdown, grammar, context-free-grammar

Markdown supports nested lists, indicated by the length of whitespace (the indent) at the beginning of each line. This is similar to Python. It seems hard to construct a parser using a context free grammar (CFG) for it. Is the grammar [context sensitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-sensitive_language) and not [context free](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy)?

Comment: Markdown is certainly not context-free, although if you just need to recognise syntactically valid Markdown, I suppose a parser which reported true for any input would be acceptable. (The MD might be semantically incorrect, or unexpectedly ugly, but I'm pretty sure *any* input will produce some output.